# Issue on project CRS loading a georeferenced image

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing

I have a georeferenced image in EPSG 26714. When I load it in Qgis 2.14 the project CRS is set to 4326. I asked for the layer properties and the CRS registered is 26714. When I open the same file in QGIS 2.87 the project is set automatically to 26714. The only way That I found to set the project CRS correctly in 2.14 is by right click on the layer and choose "set project CRS form layer". 
I geoference the layer using qgis, and a coordinate example is 545186,2172807 so it is UTM, no confusion on the coordinates. My question is why 2.14 does not recognize the CRS of the georeferenced image and assign it to to project? Why 2.86 does it as it should do it?

Comment: This also works in QGIS 2.12.3-Lyon where the project CRS gets set to the CRS of the loaded layer.

Comment: Have you looked into `Settings -> Options -> CRS`? What options are checked?

Comment: Defaul CRS for new projects: Automatically enable on the fly transformation if layers have different CRS. CRS for new layers: Use project CRS. I have not checked anything in default datum transformation. By the way these are the same options that 2.86 is using.

Comment: This is weird, if I change anything on the default CRS for new projects I have the same behavior. However if I set on CRS for new layers as use project CRS, I get a project with OTF anabled...It seems as if by default the crs of the project is set to 4326 and I have not set that

Comment: I just want to report the issue again, tested on another computer same OS (Win 10 64 bits) osgeo install...